# Renaming files in a directory using alphabetical and numerical variables

Tags: bash, unix

I commonly create directories which have sets of 24 files in them. I am trying to write a bash script which will allow me to rename these files using both alphabetical and numeric terms.

For clarification, the files are tiff images that I have taken from a 24-well plate ([Plate Layout](http://www.cellsignet.com/media/plates/24.jpg)). Using the linked image as a reference, the images were taken, by row, from left to right. So, the images are ordered first alphabetically (rows a-d), then numerically (numbers 1-6).

The files are currently named as such: IMG0001.tif, IMG0002.tif, ...

Thus, I would like to write a script which would rename the images to their respective well IDs. It would look like this:

```
a1.tif
a2.tif
a3.tif
a4.tif
a5.tif
a6.tif
b1.tif
b2.tif
...
d5.tif
d6.tif
```

It seems like it would be a fairly simple task, but nothing I have tried has even come close to giving me what I want. Could someone please recommend a way to do this using bash? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rename` is what you might be looking for.

```
$ rename IMG000 a *.tif
```

This will rename all file names with extension `.tif`, starting with `IMG000` to start with `a`.

If you have various groups, such as, `IMG000*.tif`, `IMG100*.tif`, `IMG200*.tif`, you can use multiple commands of `rename`,

```
$ rename IMG000 a IMG000*.tif
$ rename IMG100 b IMG100*.tif
$ rename IMG200 c IMG200*.tif
```

Above will rename, for example, `IMG0001.tif`, `IMG1001.tif`, `IMG2001.tif`, `IMG1002.tif` to :

```
a1.tif
b1.tif
c1.tif
b2.tif
```

....